# iPhone: Resuming background music from third-party apps like Spotify/Pandora?

Tags: iphone, ios

I a have a VOIP iOS app.my-voip-app is a push-to-talk app like Voxer where the user does not have to explicitly answer the call to speak. my-voip-app would play a notification tone and then the audio message from the sender would start playing.

I am trying to pause the background music played from third-party apps like spotify when I receive a MY-APP-VOIP call and then resume spotify music when I end MY-APP-VOIP call.

I know that the right way to do it is :

1. Receive MY-APP-VOIP call
2. AudioSessionSetActive(true); //pauses all the background audio from spotify
3. End MY-APP-VOIP call
4. AudioSessionSetActiveWithFlags(false,kAudioSessionSetActiveFlag_NotifyOthersOnDeactivation); // this will resume any paused spotify sessions.

Everything works fine when my app is in foreground.

But when my app is background and I receive a MY-APP-VOIP call, I am not able to pause the spotify.
The audio from my app and the spotify mixes with each other.

Would I not be able to get audio focus when my app is in background? Is it an iOS limitation?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?
I am facing same issue in my audio recording app.